# how to know if there is destructor of a class

Tags: c++

I need to overload new[]/delete[] to maintain memory resource.
But I found new[] will allocate 4 bytes(int) for class with destructor.
So the question is :
How to know if the new[] allocate 4 bytes for classes array to free memory correctly?

Comment: Just call sizeof(...) on the type you are allocating.

Comment: Please note the term is `destructor` not deconstructor

Comment: You should explain why you need to overload new/delte exactly.

Comment: I suspect that you're seeing the effect of a *vtable* pointer caused by a *virtual* destructor. Alternatively, you may be seeing the object count which `delete[]` needs.

Answer (score 1):

Since `new` will allocate `sizeof(Type)` bytes for your `Type` class type, you can just use that instead of hardcoding a value.

Comment: This will not include an array size. `new T[N]` may take `N*sizeof(T) + sizeof(size_t)`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that do not free in delete[] since the compiler added an int for non-simple type, just call delete and let it handle this case.